# In which ways did geometric flows and variational methods from Riemannian geometry enter the symplectic world?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I am interested to learn about the role of geometric analytic methods for solving problems in symplectic geometry, In particular, I would like to know what results heavily rely on this machinery (incl. references to the original papers and alternative explanations of the proof of technique).

Comment: Hi warzasch, and welcome to the Math.SE. I upvoted your question but nevertheless I voted also to close it: the reason is that symplectic geometry is extremely broad subject, with many applications and result. It would be almost impossible to give an exhaustive answer to such a broad question, so I invite you to consider narrowing its scope a bit, in order to provide a possible answerer the hope to give a nice answer.

Comment: I have not asked for an exhaustive answer, only for examples, a starting point.

Answer (score 6):

Symplectic Floer theory  is  essentially a variational technique.  The energy functional is the action functional on  the space of loops. Its critical points are periodic orbits of the  Hamiltonian used to defined the action  functional. The variational theory  of periodic solutions of Hamiltonian equation resembles  from this point of view the variational theory of geodesics.  The similarities stop here since the indices of these critical points are infinite so traditional Morse theory seems inapplicable.

To make  things worse, the gradient flow lines of this functional, are described by nonlinear elliptic equations similar to the Cauchy-Riemann equation. Viewed as evolution equations, the elliptic equations are ill posed.  This is a no-go  for  p.d.e. experts and explains  why people   have not investigated the gradient flow  of this action functional until Andreas Floer did.

To quote  [Freeman Dyson](https://www.ams.org/notices/200902/rtx090200212p.pdf) "*the history of mathematics is a history of horrendously difficult problems being solved by young people too ignorant to know that they were impossible*".

Symplectic Floer theory  is very challenging analytically.  As for references, you could go to the original papers of [Floer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Floer). His writing is challenging but full of great ideas.